# read command won't read file lines into multiple vars

Tags: bash-scripting

I'm very new to `bash`. I have a file named `osss` in my current working directory, and my script is:

```
read s1 s2 s3 < <( more osss) 
echo "$s1 $s2 $s3" 
exit
```

The content of `osss` is:

```
Fooo
Booo
Mooo
```

`Fooo` is assigned to `s1` but `booo` and `mooo` aren't assigned to `s2` and `s3`.

The question is: why? And where did I do it wrong?

Comment: I improved formatting of your question, not knowing whether `"` characters are in `osss` or you just used them to indicate where the content of your text file begins and ends. [Edit] if I did it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A single `read` reads a single line. Multiple words in the line may be assigned to multiple variables.

But you don't have multiple words in a single line. You have multiple lines. You need three `read` commands to read this. Or you can iterate a single command three times.

---

Additionally this fragment

```
… < <( more osss)
```

looks weird. `<osss` may be enough. I think this has nothing to do with your actual problem though.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: why? And where did I do it wrong?

The answer is you are not using the right function for the job, *and* you are using it wrong. See [man read](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html) for enlightenment, starting from where it says:

> Read **one** line

---

To accomplish what seems to be your goal I'd do:

```
readarray -t lines < osss
printf "%s " "${lines[@]}"
```

**Explanation:** First, read all the lines into an array, then print all array items separated by a space. This makes more sense than creating individual variables and using loops, and does not require knowing the total number of lines beforehand.

**Note:** The are a several tools that process text files line by line, such as `sed`, `awk`, `perl -lane`, `php -r`. Depending on what you need to do, saving the lines' contents to `bash` variables could be superfluous.